# undo or remove rule set on iptables

Tags: firewall, iptables

I have this command on `iptables`: (found on the net)

```
iptables -t mangle -A wlan0_Outgoing -m mac --mac-source ${mac} -j MARK --set-mark 2
```

please note that `${mac}` is a valid mac address.

I'm new to `iptables` so I'm not really sure how to undo it based on the given mac. I have other rules set before this but only want to undo this line if ever this is run on a specific mac address.

I have this other code that removes all the mac address:

```
iptables -t mangle -F wlan0_Outgoing
```

But I'm looking to remove specific mac address if only possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-D` command of iptables to remove a rule by specific the rule itself. For example:

```
iptables -t mangle -D wlan0_Outgoing -m mac --mac-source ${mac} -j MARK --set-mark 2
```

Will remove the rule. Alternatively you can specify the rule's line number:

```
iptables -t mangle -D wlan0_Outgoing <line-number>
```

If you need the line-numbers for your rules, you can run the following command:

```
iptables -t mangle -L --line-numbers
```

Comment: I have added a command to show the rule's line-numbers to `-L`'s output.